# React - component not updating when changed in all spots it is used

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux, redux-saga

I have a `Card` component that shows a product and then a compare check box. If this is checked then the the item should reflect that in all areas it is shown (with a checked box). This is fine from page to page however there are a few spots that item may be displayed on a carousel and on a list for relative items. So then when that list item is clicked the same item in the carousel on the same 'page' does not update until we refresh. The code is fairly large but we have a button component inside the card component which has a function in the `useEffect` to watch for changes (which works fine until the item is shown twice on one page) but again it wont update unless we refresh.

I'm sharing the code for the compare button... that's really where I feel the changes are needed:

BUTTON COMPONENT

```
export interface LikeCompareButtonProps {
  products: any[];
}

export default function LikeCompareButton({ products }: LikeCompareButtonProps) {
 const dispatch = useDispatch();
 const [checked, setChecked] = useState(false);

 const checkProducts: any[] = useAppSelector((state) => state?.compareItems?.products) 
|| [];

 const checkForChange = (products: any) => {
  if (compareView) {
    setChecked(true);
   }
   if (!compareView) {
    const checked = checkProducts?.find((x) => x.id === products?.id);
    if (checked) {
      setChecked(true);
    } else {
      setChecked(false);
    }
  }
};

const handleChange = (products: {}) => {
  if (!checked) {
    dispatch(setCompareItem(products));
    dispatch(compareItemIncreaseCounter());
    setChecked(true);
  }
  if (checked) {
    dispatch(deleteCompareItem(products));
    dispatch(compareItemDecreaseCounter());
    setChecked(false);
  }
  getCompareItem();
};

useEffect(() => {
  dispatch(getCompareItem());
  dispatch(getCompareCounter());
  checkForChange(products);
}, [checked]);

// hoping checked here would trigger every time it changes.... 
// parent component is card one. it maps through an Array -> products
return (
  <div>
    <button onClick={() => handleChange(products)}>            
      <div>
        {checked && <CheckIcon className="text-white font-bold absolute h-4 w-4" />}
      </div>
      {!checked ? "Compare" : "Remove"}
    </button>
  </div>
);
}
```

CARD COMPONENT import Link from "next/link";

```
import LikeCompareButton from "../../button/like-compare-button";

export interface SmallProductCardProps {
  products: any[];
}

export default function SmallProductCard({products}: 
SmallProductCardProps) {
return (
<>
  {products?.map((product: any, index: number) => (
    <div key={product.id} >
        <Link
          href={
               pathname: `/store/category/d/${product.id}`,
               query: { item: product.id }
               }}>
             <a>
              <img
                src="http://www.innovativeengsystems.com/wp-c 
              ontent/uploads/2017/11/no-img-portrait.png"
                alt={product.id}
              />
            )}
          </a>
         </Link>
          <LikeCompareButton
            products={products[index]}
          />  
     </div>
   ))}
 </>
 );
```

}

HOME: WHERE PRODUCTS IS DEFINED

```
const Home: NextPage = () => {
const dispatch = useDispatch();
const products: any[] = useAppSelector((state) => 
 state?.products?.products?.data);

 useEffect(() => {
   dispatch(getProductList()); //API RENDERED DATA 
  }, []);
 return (
   <>
  <SectionLayout hero={true}>
      <InnerGridViewLayout colSize={"col-span-4 grid-cols-2 grid- 
     rows-2 pt-0"}>
        <SmallProductCard
          products={products}
        />
      </InnerGridViewLayout>  
  </SectionLayout> 
</>
);
};

export default Home;
```

Adding REDUX work
ACTIONS

```
export const setCompareItem = (products: any) => {
  return {
    type: SET_COMPARE_ITEM,
    payload: products
  };
};

export const setCompareItemSuccessful = (products: any) => {
  localStorage.setItem("item", JSON.stringify(products.payload));

  const existingItems: any[] = 
  JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("compareItems")!) ?? [];
  existingItems?.push(products.payload);

  localStorage.setItem("compareItems", 
  JSON.stringify(existingItems));

  return {
    type: SET_COMPARE_ITEM_SUCCESSFUL,
    payload: products
   };
 };

 export const getCompareItem = () => {
   return {
     type: GET_COMPARE_ITEM,
     payload: []
   };
 };

 export const getCompareItemSuccessful = () => {
   var products: any[] = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("compareItems")!);
   return {
     type: GET_COMPARE_ITEM_SUCCESSFUL,
     payload: products
   };
 };
```

REDUCER

```
import {
ERROR_COMPARE,
SET_COMPARE_ITEM,
SET_COMPARE_ITEM_SUCCESSFUL,
GET_COMPARE_ITEM,
GET_COMPARE_ITEM_SUCCESSFUL,
DELETE_COMPARE_ITEM
} from "./actionTypes";

const compareItemsState = {
  products: [],
  loading: false,
  message: ""
 };

const reducer = (state = compareItemsState, action) => {
 switch (action.type) {
 case SET_COMPARE_ITEM:
  state = {
    ...state,
    products: [action.payload],
    message: "item added"
  };
  break;
case SET_COMPARE_ITEM_SUCCESSFUL:
  state = {
    ...state,
    products: [action.payload],
    message: "set item success"
  };
  break;
case GET_COMPARE_ITEM:
  state = {
    ...state,
    products: action.payload,
    message: "item found success"
  };
  break;
case GET_COMPARE_ITEM_SUCCESSFUL:
  state = {
    ...state,
    products: action.payload,
    message: "found item"
  };
  break;
case DELETE_COMPARE_ITEM:
  state = {
    ...state,
    products: action.payload,
    message: "item deleted"
  };
  break;
  case ERROR_COMPARE:
    state = {
    ...state,
    compareCounter: state.compareCounter,
    message: "Error adding message"
  };
  break;
default:
  state = { ...state };
  break;
}
return state;
};
export default reducer;
```

SAGA.tsx

```
import { takeEvery, fork, put, all, call } from "redux- 
saga/effects";
import {
  SET_COMPARE_ITEM,
  SET_COMPARE_ITEM_SUCCESSFUL,
  DELETE_COMPARE_ITEM,
  GET_COMPARE_ITEM_SUCCESSFUL,
  GET_COMPARE_ITEM,
} from "./actionTypes";
import {
 compareError,
 setCompareItem,
 setCompareItemSuccessful,
 deleteCompareItem,
 getCompareItem,
 getCompareItemSuccessful,
} from "./actions";

function* setCompareItems(product: any) {
  try {
   yield put(setCompareItem(product));
  } catch (error: any) {
   yield put(compareError("Item not added, please try again."));
 }
}

function* setCompareItemsSuccessful(products: any) {
 try {
   yield put(setCompareItemSuccessful(products));
 } catch (error: any) {
   yield put(compareError("Item not removed, please try 
  again."));
 }
}

function* getCompareItems() {
  try {
   yield put(getCompareItem());
  } catch (error: any) {
   yield put(compareError("please try again."));
  }
}

function* getCompareItemsSuccessful() {
  try {
   yield put(getCompareItemSuccessful());
  } catch (error: any) {
   yield put(compareError("please try again."));
  }
}
function* setDeleteItems(products: any) {
  try {
   yield put(deleteCompareItem(products));
  } catch (error: any) {
    yield put(compareError("Item removed"));
 }
}

export function* watchSetCompareItemSuccess() {
 yield takeEvery(SET_COMPARE_ITEM_SUCCESSFUL, setCompareItems);
}
export function* watchSetCompareItem() {
 yield takeEvery(SET_COMPARE_ITEM, setCompareItemsSuccessful);
}
export function* watchGetCompareItemSuccess() {
 yield takeEvery(GET_COMPARE_ITEM_SUCCESSFUL, getCompareItems);
}
export function* watchGetCompareItem() {
 yield takeEvery(GET_COMPARE_ITEM, getCompareItemsSuccessful);
}
export function* watchDeleteCompareItem() {
 yield takeEvery(DELETE_COMPARE_ITEM, setDeleteItems);
}
function* compareItemStoreSaga() {
  yield all([
   fork(watchSetCompareItem),
   fork(watchGetCompareItem),
  ]);
}
export default compareItemStoreSaga;
```

Comment: Can we see `setCompareItem`? If it's pushing into an existing `state.compareItems.products` array (as opposed to creating a new array) it's likely the component isn't updating because React is doing an identity comparison to determine whether to re-render. If it's not a new array it won't re-render even if the contents of the array have changed. Your local component re-renders because you're also changing local state with `setChecked`.

Comment: Why isn't this "checked" state part of your redux state? Or is it and this code has overcomplicated things by duplicating a "checked" state locally in the component? The Redux store *should* be the source of truth, and all components will access it if they are subscribing to the store. `products: any[];` is a most-unuseful type declaration, and then later the code is accessing a `products.id` property, which shouldn't exist on an array. Can you edit the post to include a more complete [mcve] so we've better context around the code and what it's possibly doing?

Comment: @ray the redux actions
export const setCompareItem = (products: any) => {
  return {
    type: SET_COMPARE_ITEM,
    payload: products
  };
};

export const setCompareItemSuccessful = (products: any) => {
  localStorage.setItem("item", JSON.stringify(products.payload));
  const existingItems: any[] = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("compareItems")!) ?? [];
  existingItems?.push(products.payload);
  localStorage.setItem("compareItems", JSON.stringify(existingItems));
  return {
    type: SET_COMPARE_ITEM_SUCCESSFUL,
    payload: products
  };
};

Comment: @DrewReese it is not part of the state only bc i did not understand why or why to include it.... we just save the products to local storage and create a new array there then 

then find it with the 
      const checked = checkProducts?.find((x) => x.id === products?.id); that is inside the function that is in useEffect

Comment: Can you put the relevant code in the question so we don't have to visually parse it from a single long wrapped line in a comment?

Comment: i did add it above

Comment: Can you include all relevant code, e.g. the reducer functions handling these dispatched actions, where/how the `LikeCompareButton` component is rendered, and where the `products` prop is declared?

Comment: thanks drew added the files above

Comment: Shouldn't `checkProducts` be part of the `useEffect` dependencies? So that when it changes `checkForChange` is called?

Comment: you know i didnt try that dependency let me get to that.

Comment: @MartinKadlec ok that helped but i get 
 Warning: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component calls setState inside useEffect, but useEffect either doesn't have a dependency array, or one of the dependencies changes on every render.